# ListMultiplechoice wicket behaving differently when selecting list from bottom to top

Tags: ajax, wicket

I have a ListMultipleChoice which has a Ajax Behavior. When I try to select the list using (Shift + DownArrow), it's not letting me select more than 10 rows. It's just moving up after reaching 10 selections. Whereas, when I select from bottom to top, it's letting me select properly. I know it sounds weird, but that's what this is. Can someone help me with this issue.

Code from comment:

```
users = new ListMultipleChoice<User>("userList", new PropertyModel<List<User>>( this, "userList"), userModel, new FrUserChoiceRenderer());
```

Comment: Can you show some relevant code? Like how you create the ListMultipleChoice, the AjaxBehaviour? Can you create a minimal quickstart to reproduce the problem? Does this affect all browsers? If no, which one is affected?

Comment: users = new ListMultipleChoice<User>("userList", new PropertyModel<List<User>>(this, "userList"), userModel, new FrUserChoiceRenderer());

users.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onChange") {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    getSession().cleanupFeedbackMessages();
log.info("Size of the user list is " + userList.size());
if (userList.size() == 1) {
User user = userList.get(0);
rolesGroup = user.getUserRole();
target.add(group);
} else { 
rolesGroup = null;     target.add(group);   
}}});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it on different browsers and see what happens. What does this `AjaxEventBehavior` do exactly? Does it work without this `AjaxEventBehavior`? Does it work with a plain html `<select>` list? What have you tried yourself? Show some code.

Comment: @Nicktar Hi Nicktar. Working on a different browser did the trick.
It was not working on mozilla, I tried using IE and it's working just fine.